# Where is sqlite3_native.rb in Windows with Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ruby-2.0, sqlite3-ruby

Using Ruby 2.0 x64 on Windows. Installed sqlite3 gem by downloading the sqlite3 autoconf sources and compiling. Then I did a `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby ...`. However, now when I run `rails server`, I get the following error. Where is this sqlite3_native.rb? I can't find it anywhere.

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Users/me/my_project/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you installed the DevKit and copied the .dll's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4413168) for installing SQLite3 with Ruby 2.0 on Windows.

It is rather a complicated process. Follow the tutorial and see if it works after that.